# How to modify QTreeWidget Selection Behavior

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, pyqt5, qtreewidget

The code below creates a single `QTreeWidget`.
Clicking any item adds it to the current selection (QTreeWidget is set to support `MultiSelection`). But I would like to only add to the current selection when Shift or Command modifier key is used.

[image]

```
app = QApplication([])
widget = QTreeWidget()
widget.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.MultiSelection)
widget.setColumnCount(5)
for row in range(7):
    item = QTreeWidgetItem(widget)
    for col in range(5):
        item.setText(col, 'Column %s' % col)
widget.show()
qApp.exec_()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `mouseMoveEvent` and `mousePressEvent` methods must be overwritten and in it decide if any action is taken or not.

```
class TreeWidget(QTreeWidget):
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if QApplication.keyboardModifiers()&(Qt.ShiftModifier|Qt.ControlModifier):
            QTreeWidget.mouseMoveEvent(self, event)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if QApplication.keyboardModifiers()&(Qt.ShiftModifier|Qt.ControlModifier):
            QTreeWidget.mousePressEvent(self, event)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    widget = TreeWidget()
    widget.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.MultiSelection)
    widget.setColumnCount(5)
    for row in range(7):
        item = QTreeWidgetItem(widget)
        for col in range(5):
            item.setText(col, 'Column %s' % col)
    widget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1):

Only change Multiselection by ExtendedSelection. Would be:
`widget.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection)`

Documentation qt5 (version 5.13) https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#SelectionMode-enum